# How to add multiple user credentials for a mobile application using jmeter

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing, mobile-application

[1]When i record the actions of my mobile device the user credentials are stored in the HTTP authorization manager. how to add multiple datas in it.

I have the data in a csv file. Should i convert it to txt file as there is an option to load file in HTTP authorization manager or any other options to do it.

[the actions are recorded under recording controller]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uv0mJ.png

Answer (score 0):

[HTTP Authorization Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) can be parameterized normally using [CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG).

Given you have [CSV file (in text format)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/import-or-export-text-txt-or-csv-files-5250ac4c-663c-47ce-937b-339e391393ba) which looks like:

```
username1,password1
username2,password2
etc.
```

You can add CSV Data Set Config to your test plan and configure it like:

[image]

Then in the HTTP Authorization Manager you can use the variables defined in the CSV Data Set Config:

[image]

And when you run the test each virtual user will  read next line on each iteration resulting in the generation of the relevant [Authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) header

[image]

Comment: i have edited the question by adding a link of the screenshot. all my actions are recorded under recording controller. should i add csv under recording controller

Comment: It should work at Test Plan level as well, see [Scoping Rules](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) user manual entry for more details. You can see [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) which are generated, [pre-defined](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#predefinedvars) or originate from the CSV Data Set Config using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debug-jmeter) combination

Comment: can you send a screenshot it will be very helpful. When i record the login action then modify it by adding csv file it only gives the response for the data which i used to login from mobile. am i doing it right ?